# WP Вывод изображения записи. Зачем так много вариантов

Tags: wordpress, изображения, оптимизация-сайтов

Недавно инспектировал сайт на WordPress и попался мне такой вівод изображния записи.

```
<div class="acf-af-side-by-side-numbers-and-carousel__image-list-item active" data-image-item="1" style="z-index: 3; right: calc(200px); bottom: calc(0px);">
                    <img decoding="async" src="https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1.png" width="447" class="acf-af-side-by-side-numbers-and-carousel__image entered lazyloaded" data-lazy-srcset="https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1.png 447w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-242x300.png 242w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-48x60.png 48w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-165x205.png 165w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-200x248.png 200w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-284x353.png 284w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-322x400.png 322w" data-lazy-sizes="(max-width: 447px) 100vw, 447px" alt="" data-lazy-src="https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1.png" data-ll-status="loaded" sizes="(max-width: 447px) 100vw, 447px" srcset="https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1.png 447w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-242x300.png 242w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-48x60.png 48w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-165x205.png 165w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-200x248.png 200w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-284x353.png 284w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-322x400.png 322w"><noscript><img decoding="async" 
            src="https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1.png" 
            width="447" 
            class="acf-af-side-by-side-numbers-and-carousel__image" 
            srcset="https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1.png 447w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-242x300.png 242w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-48x60.png 48w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-165x205.png 165w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-200x248.png 200w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-284x353.png 284w, https://static.tytocare.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Mask-group1-322x400.png 322w" 
            sizes="(max-width: 447px) 100vw, 447px" 
            alt="" 
        ></noscript></div>
```

К сожалению, не получилось у автора сайта спросить зачем так много альтернативных вариантов изображения и как они должны работать, но возможно тут смогу получить объяснение?

*лично я при выводе изображений запити пользуюсь вот таким кодом

```
<?php $post_id = $post->ID;
$img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id);
if (!$img) {
        $img = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/no-image/min.svg';
} ?>

<img class="post_img" src="<?php echo $img ?>" width="320" height="400" alt="<?php echo $title ?>">
```

Может кто-то объяснить, зачем выводить изображения так как показано в первом примере, и как это реализуеться? Ведь насколько читал из документации, то WP сам наризает размеры изображений при загрузке, но они обычно меньшего формата чем загружаемое изображение. (`Settings\Media`)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset

Comment: serset - это правильно (см. коментарий выше). Поэтому WP выводит так, как положено. А вы выводите неправильно.

Comment: Я читал документацию, но как можно такой важный параметр как размер и качество изображения отдавать на разсмотрение браузера...? Почему не используеться тег `<picture>` где чотко можно контролировать, что для мобильных устройст отдаем. Мы точно знаем, что нам не надо нагружать пересовкой размеры изображения для мобильного устройства... Не надо нам изображение 1000х1000рх для мобилки, если экран у нас 490рх.